# IntelliSense tooltip not displaying correct Typescript event types on hover in vscode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, types

[What I see on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP2Ox.png)

[What I want to see on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56cXT.png)